# Multiply group by functions mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

The problem comes when I was trying to calculate correlation in group.
[image]

When I have multiple groups I need to do something like this for the numerator:

```
sum((x - avg(x)) * (y - avg(y)))
```

I was hoping that the inner `x - avg()` will perform subtract for every x. But turns out I can't do this in MySQL like this

```sql
select sum((x - avg(x)) * (y - avg(y))) numerator
from tbl t group by group_colk
```

This gives invalid use of group function. There are 3 ways to get around this afaik.

1. Layout the formula some other way so that it doesn't contain 2 aggregate functions. Which sometimes is hard because I can't find other forms online easily.
2. Create another table that calculates the inner aggregated result (the mean in this case). Join it with another for the outer one (the sum). This way will have me join another table that causes performance loss.
3. Use variables to store the results. This will have me run the query for more than once to get the result.

Is there any better way to get around this? Haven't try subqueries yet but it seems subqueries hurts more performance than joining another table based on my past experience.

Comment: *You get the idea.* Your optimism is misplaced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Math - Is it possible to calculate a correlation in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457645/mysql-math-is-it-possible-to-calculate-a-correlation-in-a-query)

Comment: @P.Salmon This is the third approach I used. Not quite what I want still. I already did this but it's too much overhead for deployment so I want a single query to get the job done..

Comment: @Strawberry Haha. I use python a lot so I thought this is a common sense. The idea is that I want some way to not 'collapse' the group into one row when I do x-avg(x) but do when I sum it up.

Comment: 'but it's too much overhead for the script.' - how so? Representative Sample data and expected outcome would help , especially for those who have not done difficult sums in a decade or 4.

Comment: @P.Salmon The sample in the link require one select to set the variable and another to use the variable. I want one query and one join to make it work. The problem wasn't specifically for regression but to find a way to get around using an aggregate function inside another aggregate function but not in the ways I've listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Precompute the averages, then get to work on the main formula:

```
select grp, sum((x - avgx) * (y - avgy)) numerator
    FROM ( SELECT grp,
                  avg(x) AS avgx, 
                  avg(y) AS avgy
              FROM tbl
         ) AS z
    JOIN tbl  USING(grp)
    group by grp;
```

Assuming that works OK, enhance it to do the whole formula:

```
 SELECT grp, ( sum((..)*(..)) ) /
             ( SQRT( ... ) )  as Correlation
```